# SSRS Render Multiple Pages from Report in C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a service that renders a report from SSRS which works perfectly fine with one page, however when I tried to change the code to render multiple pages separately I can't seem to get it to work as expected.

I used a guide on the MSDN blogs (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanke/archive/2004/02/11/71491.aspx#code) to try and achieve this, but my StreamIDs doesn't seem to be working as I expected.

Here's my code from the Render() method onwards (the rest seems to be okay, but I can provide on request):

```cs
    var firstPage = rsExec.Render(format.ToString(), deviceInfo,
        out extension, out encoding,
        out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
            var numberOfPages = streamIDs.Length + 1;

            results = new Byte[numberOfPages][];
            results[0] = firstPage;

            if (numberOfPages > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    deviceInfo = $@"
                        <DeviceInfo>
                            <OutputFormat>JPEG</OutputFormat>
                            <StartPage>{i + 1}</StartPage>
                        </DeviceInfo>";
                    results[i] = rsExec.Render(format.ToString(), deviceInfo,
                        out extension, out encoding,
                        out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
                }
            }
```

This generates the report okay, but I expected the streamIDs to become the number of extra pages required, but it always only has one entry in it. Am I doing something stupidly wrong here?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.